# How to fix transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have Android application which was working fine but few hours ago it started showing me error on `Run 'app' click` in Android Studio:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Execution can fall off end of the code
```

If I build app from console like `gradle assembleRelease` everything works fine.

So my question is how to fix this, what could cause this problem. It drives me crazy, because I can't start my app only from Android Studio.

Btw: I already tried to google it and a lot of answers about multidex problem but I guess it's not an option in my case.

Answer (score 6):

## Delete build dir

Try deleting the contents of your build directory, and then rebuilding.

`appName/build` and/or `appName/app/build`

#### Alternatively, clean your build

A less brute force option to try is to clean the build.

`Build -> Clean Project` or `Build -> Rebuild Project`